# Write embedded semicolon ascii as human readable

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, ascii

I have a tab delimited text file with the ascii symbols for semicolons and equal signs within some of the fields I am parsing; i.e. \x3b and \x3d.  I am not able to figure out how to convert them back in my code, although at the command line it is done automatically.

I have tried using codecs and encode for reading and writing, as well as string.replace

```
temp[8].replace("\x3b",";")
```

```
file=codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='ascii') # or utf-8
```

I would like to see:
dist=7117;dist=1508

but I am just getting the input string:
dist\x3d7117\x3bdist\x3d1508

When I type this at a python command line:

> unicode("dist\x3d7117\x3bdist\x3d1508")

The output is:

> dist=7117;dist=1508

When I put this into my code:

```
print unicode(dist\x3d7117\x3bdist\x3d1508)
```

I get 
dist=7117;dist=1508

But when I put in the variable holding this string

```
print unicode(temp[7])
```

I get:
dist\x3d7117\x3bdist\x3d1508

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be certain without seeing the `repr` of the data, but this ought to work:

```
>>> s = 'dist\\x3d7117\\x3bdist\\x3d1508'
>>> fixed = s.decode('string-escape')
>>> print fixed
dist=7117;dist=1508
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me that, works perfectly! I implemented as follows:


temp[8].decode('string-escape')